# Аудит авторизации пользователя

Tags: sql-server

Хочу отследить авторизации пользователей в SQL. Если точнее - с какой машины логинятся под пользователем SA. И отправлять сообщение на почту, если у машины та или иная маска.
Помогите пожалуйста создать запрос.

Comment: Какая маска у машины то? ИП адреса и маска сети? и это Гугл переводил - `аудит успеха пользователя` ?

Comment: маска имени компьютеров к примеру tom-cc-op*(01,02,03,04) ip адреса могут быть разные, "аудит успеха" успешный вход в инстанс под УЗ SA

Comment: Если хотите чтоб помогли, сформулируйте понятно вопрос, на чем надо сформировать запрос, платформа, среда итд.

Comment: Нужен образец запроса в sql server 2012 на создание процедуры которая будет вытаскивать в отдельную таблицу - список авторизаций под УЗ SA с указанием компьютеров с определённой маской.

Answer (score 1):

1. Включаем аудит успешных логинов сервера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Читаем информацию из ERRORLOG-файла(ов), используя недокументированную функцию `xp_readerrorlog`.

[Статья на бусурманском](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1476/reading-the-sql-server-log-files-using-tsql/)

> Эта процедура принимает четыре параметра:
>
> 1. Номер файла журнала ошибок, который вы хотите прочитать:
>
>    0 = текущий,
>
>    1 = архив №1,
>
>    2 = архив № 2 и т. д.
> 2. Тип файла журнала: 1 или NULL = журнал ошибок, 2 = журнал агента SQL
> 3. Строка поиска 1: строка, которую вы хотите найти
> 4. Строка поиска 2: Строка два, которую вы хотите найти, чтобы уточнить результаты

Пример скрипта с отбором из двух последних файлов журнала, возвращается дата, логин, адрес:

```
    CREATE TABLE #Temp (
        LogDate     DATETIME,
        ProcessInfo NVARCHAR(32),
        [Text]      NVARCHAR(4000)
    )

    INSERT #Temp(LogDate, ProcessInfo, [Text])
    EXECUTE xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'login', N'CLIENT:'

    INSERT #Temp(LogDate, ProcessInfo, [Text])
    EXECUTE xp_readerrorlog 1, 1, N'login', N'CLIENT:'

    ;WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT LogDate, 
        SUBSTRING([text], CHARINDEX(CHAR(39), [text]) + 1, PATINDEX('%''.%', [text]) - CHARINDEX(CHAR(39), [text]) - 1) AS LoginName,
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING([text], PATINDEX('%CLIENT: %', [text]) + 8, 100), ']', '') AS Addr
        FROM #Temp
        WHERE ProcessInfo = 'Logon' 
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM cte
    WHERE LoginName = 'SA'
    order by LogDate DESC

    DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Для аудита успешной авторизации лучше всего, на мой взгляд, подойдёт триггер уровня сервера на событие `LOGON`, внутри которого можно обратиться к системному представлению *sys.dm_exec_sessions* (плюс, возможно, к *sys.dm_exec_connections*), чтобы собрать интересующую информацию о пользователе и/или соединении.

Что-то наподобие такого:

```
USE [master];
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [AfterLogon]
ON ALL SERVER
WITH EXECUTE AS 'AuditLogon'
AFTER LOGON
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [Audit].[Log].[SA_Logon] (LoginTime, HostName)
    SELECT
        s.login_time, s.host_name
    FROM
        sys.dm_exec_sessions s
    WHERE
        s.session_id = @@spid
        AND s.original_login_name = N'sa'
        AND s.host_name LIKE N'tom-cc-op%'
        AND s.is_user_process = 1;

END;
GO
```

Перед созданием триггера потребуется следующее.

Создать БД для аудита:

```
USE [master];
GO
CREATE DATABASE [Audit];
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Audit] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE; 
GO
```

В этой БД - создать таблицу, в которую будет собираться необходимая информация:

```
USE [Audit];
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [Log] AUTHORIZATION [dbo];
GO
CREATE TABLE [Log].[SA_Logon]
(
    Id bigint IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    LoginTime datetime2(3) NOT NULL,
    HostName nvarchar(128) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_SA_Logon PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
GO
```

Также потребуется специальный логин, от имени которого будет исполняться код триггера

```
USE [master];
GO
CREATE LOGIN [AuditLogon]
    WITH PASSWORD = N'SomeStrongPassword', CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF;
GO
DENY CONNECT SQL TO [AuditLogon];
GO
```

(логин будет использоваться только триггером, поэтому самостоятельное подключение к SqlServer ему запрещаем).

И последнее, что потребуется - пользователь в БД аудита, связанный с логином, которому нужно дать права на вставку данных в таблицу, в которую собирается информация:

```
USE [Audit];
GO
CREATE USER [AuditLogon] FOR LOGIN [AuditLogon];
GO
GRANT INSERT ON OBJECT::[Log].[SA_Logon] TO [AuditLogon];  
GO
```